# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 2167)

Tags: python, json

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
print(response.text)
print(type(response.text))
print(json.loads(response.text))
```

Result

```
{"sku_id":"H7047001_S_24SM-2021130001B","primary_category_code":"AA31554520001","primary_category_name_en":"Gadgets & Electronics > Camera & Accessories > Camera Bag & Strap & Protector > Screen Protector","primary_category_name_chi":"大腦場 > 攝影器材 > 相機袋 相機帶 屏幕保護 > 屏幕保護","cat_codes":"AA31554520001","cat_names_en":"Gadgets & Electronics > Camera & Accessories > Camera Bag & Strap & Protector > Screen Protector","cat_names_chi":"大腦場 > 攝影器材 > 相機袋 相機帶 屏幕保護 > 屏幕保護","name_en":"iPhone 13 Pro Max tempered glass screen protector (suitable for iphone 13 )","name_chi":"iphone 13 Pro 鋼化保護貼(iphone 13 6.1通用)","brand_name_en":"hoco.","brand_name_chi":"hoco.","summary_en":"<p>1. PC nano edge, not broken edge<br/>2. The frame is higher than the glass surface to prevent the screen from breaking<br/>3. 3D arc edge<br/>4. Thickness 0.33mm<br/></p>","summary_chi":"<p>1，PC納米邊，不碎邊<br/>2，邊框高出玻璃面，防止摔碎屏幕<br/>3，3D弧邊<br/>4，厚度0.33mm<br/></p>","description_en":null,"description_chi":null,"image_urls":"https://cdn-mms.hktvmall.com/hktv/mms/uploadProductImage/c566/17e4/6c51/JmaqphYnzt20211130215445_1200.jpg | https://cdn-mms.hktvmall.com/hktv/mms/uploadProductImage/6f12/126c/4331/RyLUqftEEq20211130215435_1200.jpg | https://cdn-mms.hktvmall.com/hktv/mms/uploadProductImage/7820/ccd1/4779/AhlVGiJOgN20211130215443_1200.jpg","creation_time":"2021-11-30T21:57:23+08:00","store_code":"H7047001","original_price":99.0,"discount_price":49.000000500000006,"stock_available":5,"out_of_stock_since":null,"max_order_quantity":null,"total_shipped_quantity":null,"manu_country_en":"China","manu_country_chi":"中國","height":100.0,"length":50.0,"width":20.0,"dimension_unit":"mm","weight":0.1,"weight_unit":"kg","colors":null,"storage_type":"","packing_spec_en":"","packing_spec_chi":"","packing_box_type":"F","delivery_mode":"hktv-standard-delivery","pickup_days":"1/2/3/4/5/6","num_days_to_be_ready":0,"online_date":null,"offline_date":null,"loyalty_point":0.0,"shelf_life":0.0,"warranty_period":0,"warranty_period_unit":null,"warranty_supplier_en":null,"warranty_supplier_chi":null,"virtual_store_code":null,"virtual_store_name_en":null,"virtual_store_name_chi":null,"primary_store":"H7047001"}
{"sku_id":"H7047001_S_24SM-20210705002","primary_category_code":"AA73502030001","primary_category_name_en":"Sports & Travel > Outdoor Personal Cares > Sun Care > UV Shield Sun Sleeves","primary_category_name_chi":"運動旅行 > 戶外護理用品 > 防矖用品 > 防曬手袖","cat_codes":"AA73502030001","cat_names_en":"Sports & Travel > Outdoor Personal Cares > Sun Care > UV Shield Sun Sleeves","cat_names_chi":"運動旅行 > 戶外護理用品 > 防矖用品 > 防曬手袖","name_en":"MIT Children's Effective Cooling Mosquito Anti-UV Sleeve-American Eagle","name_chi":"『台灣製』兒童高效涼感防蚊抗UV袖套-美國鷹","brand_name_en":"24-LS","brand_name_chi":"24-LS","summary_en":"1. Add Tanatex EULAN natural and powerful anti-mosquito ingredients<br />2. SGS certified UPF50+ effective sun protection!<br />3. The formaldehyde-free ingredients can be worn by children with peace of mind<br />4. Effectively avoid all kinds of mosquito bites<br />5. Ice ore coffee cool yarn material, cool to the touch and fast heat dissipation<br />6. Using Lycra elastic fiber, it fits snugly and is washable<br />7. Can be used as a foot cover","summary_chi":"1. 添加Tanatex EULAN類天然強效防蚊成分<br />2. SGS認證UPF50+有效防曬!<br />3. 無甲醛成份可以安心讓小朋友配帶<br />4. 有效避免各種蚊蟲叮咬<br />5. 冰礦咖啡涼感紗材質，觸感清涼，散熱快<br />6. 使用萊卡彈性纖維，服貼合身耐水洗<br />7.可當腳套","description_en":"Composition: 90% nylon (coffee yarn), 10% elastic fiber<br />. Specifications: Children's sleeves<br />. Size: Flat size: about 30CM long, arm width 7.5CM/maximum stretch: about 84CM long, 20CM arm width<br />. Origin: Taiwan","description_chi":"成分：尼龍90%(咖啡紗)、彈性纖維10%<br />．規格：兒童袖套<br />．尺寸：平量尺寸:約長30CM，臂寬7.5CM/最大拉伸:約長84CM，臂寬20CM<br />．產地：台灣","image_urls":"https://images.hktv-img.com/images/HKTV/23661/24SM-20210705002_main_67904340_20210705222213_01_1200.jpg","creation_time":"2021-07-05T15:20:00+08:00","store_code":"H7047001","original_price":99.0,"discount_price":59.0000004,"stock_available":1,"out_of_stock_since":null,"max_order_quantity":null,"total_shipped_quantity":2,"manu_country_en":"Taiwan","manu_country_chi":"台灣","height":80.0,"length":50.0,"width":20.0,"dimension_unit":"mm","weight":0.1,"weight_unit":"kg","colors":null,"storage_type":"","packing_spec_en":"","packing_spec_chi":"","packing_box_type":"H","delivery_mode":"hktv-standard-delivery","pickup_days":"1/2/3/4/5/6","num_days_to_be_ready":0,"online_date":null,"offline_date":"2099-01-01T00:00:00+08:00","loyalty_point":0.0,"shelf_life":0.0,"warranty_period":null,"warranty_period_unit":null,"warranty_supplier_en":null,"warranty_supplier_chi":null,"virtual_store_code":null,"virtual_store_name_en":null,"virtual_store_name_chi":null,"primary_store":"H7047001"}

<class 'str'>

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 2167)
```

How can I solve this problem? I am stuck in json.loads.

I would like to put it into dictionary and then put it into dataframe and export into csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have two dictionaries in the response text, therefore you can do:

```
json_responses = response.text.split('\n')
for item in json_responses:
    if item != '':
        print(json.loads(item))
```

to load each of the dictionaries.

Comment: it is not dictionaries! 
It is two string.
I tried your code and it is not working.
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: its only one string? you call response.text only once but get two lines of text? Does it print() out anything or is that happen for the first time through the loop? Try this new version.

Comment: It's work!!!! Thanks!!!